# Gulp error traversal module

Tags: node.js, npm, vagrant, gulp, homestead

I am running a Homestead virtual machine and when I run Gulp I got this error message.
I read so many topics on the web and I tried these, but not working.

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/crm.activix.local$ gulp module.js:339
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../traversal'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:337:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/Code/crm.activix.local/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/plugin-pass.js:19:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
```

Answer (score 1):

Homestead and Gulp is a strange thing. I've never gotten it to work properly when running gulp and npm commands inside my Homestead VM.

I use windows, so I have to use gith bash from windows to make gulp/npm stuff work properly. I believe the issue has to do with windows pathing. Take this path from the laravel-elixir install
`myproject\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\gulplog\node_modules\glogg\node_modules\sparkles`

So dependencies have hteir own dependencies, who have their own dependencies, etc.

When you try to install this, and it has to "mirror" the files on your windows system, it just breaks. At least that's what I think happens.

So to be safe, install node.js on your computer, and run all gulp/npm commands from there. At least that's what I need to do.